# When callbacks won't be called in event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, shadow-dom

Well I wrote the following code:

```html
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.innerHTML = "<div></div>";
  let outerHost = document.querySelectorAll("div")[0];
  outerHost.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  outerHost.shadowRoot.innerHTML = "<style>div {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red}</style><div></div><div id='host-shadow'></div>";

  let target = outerHost.shadowRoot.childNodes[2];
  target.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  target.shadowRoot.innerHTML = "<div id='node-text' style='background-color: green'>Hello</div>";
  let relatedTarget = target.shadowRoot.childNodes[0];

  let ev = new Event("mouseover");
  ev.relatedTarget = relatedTarget;
  target.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => console.log(e.target, e.relatedTarget));
  target.dispatchEvent(ev);
});
</script>
```

It creates two shadow roots and to the `id="host-shadow"` appoint event listener `mouseover`.

If I set my cursor onto `id="node-text"` and then move it to the `id="host-shadow"` I won't get the invocation of callback of the event listener. But If I do it by synthetic method I get the callback invocation. I'am stuck!

Look at the [spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch):

> If target is not relatedTarget or target is event’s relatedTarget, then:

If this condition passing examination, then you getting your callback invocation, otherwise you won't.

As I can compare not sythetic invocation and synthetic, them invocations don't pass the examination. Why does synthetic invocation pass and call callback?

**My question:** what actually do this condition that I specify above?

Comment: I apologize; I didn't fully get your situation. So, to begin with, if I provide such an explanation, do you think we already have a mutual understanding? 
'My question: what actually do this condition that I specify above?'
'This means that if the target of the event (the element that the event is being triggered on) is not the same as the relatedTarget (the element that the event is coming from), then the specified action should be taken.'

Comment: @МаксимМовчан you understand right. Also don't forget second part of condition "... or target is event’s relatedTarget, then:"

Comment: docs say ``relatedTarget`` is read-only.

Comment: Ok. I thought about it, but still there were some incomprehensible moments. 
I have a question for you (perhaps this will help clarify). 
Why do you think that sythetic invocation don't pass the examination?
From your code the TARGET is always <div id="host-shadow"></div> and 
relatedTarget is either <div id='node-text'></div> or div from this string 'document.body.innerHTML = "<div></div>"'
Therefore, since TARGET and relatedTarget are separate nodes, the condition from spec is triggered immediately.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I know, but you may successfully make your own property on event if it doesn't have a default `relatedTarget`

Comment: ``relatedTarget`` is the element the mouse has left?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman nah, it is that case when event dont't  initialized by browser `relatedTarget` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you were assuming you could set the `Event`'s `relatedTarget` by setting a property with that name on the instance object. That is not how this works. The `relatedTarget` in your quote of the specs is an internal property of the instance, and it's not exposed to JS. It's currently called like that in the specs, but it could be changed tomorrow to another name without any consequences, because it's not exposed.

For a property to have an influence, it needs to be exposed as a setter on the Interface. Currently the [`Event` interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#event) only exposes the `cancelBubble` and `returnValue` attributes as settable. All other attributes are *readonly*. You can set a few more properties like `.type`, `.bubbles`, `.cancelable` and `.composed` through the constructor call, and the call to `dispatchEvent()` will determine the `.target` and `.timestamp` one, but `relatedTarget` is simply not of this list and there is nothing you can do to set it.

Now, the [`MouseEvent` interface](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#dom-mouseevent-relatedtarget) does expose its internal `relatedTarget` through the *readonly* `.relatedTarget` attribute, and it allows setting it through the eponymous property of the [MouseEventInit dictionary](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#idl-mouseeventinit). So for a `MouseEvent`, you can actually set it.

Setting it to what you tried to do, the callback will not be called, because the "result of [retargeting](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#retarget) event’s `relatedTarget` against `target`" would be `target` (we hit the third bullet in the algo and thus return  `A` directly which is `target`), but the event's `relatedTarget` (the one we did set) is not `target`.

```html
<div></div>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  let outerHost = document.querySelectorAll("div")[0];
  outerHost.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  outerHost.shadowRoot.innerHTML = "<style>div {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red}</style><div></div><div id='host-shadow'></div>";

  let target = outerHost.shadowRoot.childNodes[2];
  target.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  target.shadowRoot.innerHTML = "<div id='node-text' style='background-color: green'>Hello</div>";
  let relatedTarget = target.shadowRoot.childNodes[0];

  // Use the MouseEvent interface to set relatedTarget
  let ev = new MouseEvent("mouseover", { relatedTarget });
  // Won't fire
  target.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => console.log(e.target, e.relatedTarget));
  target.dispatchEvent(ev);
  console.log("Event dispatched");
});
</script>
```

Comment: I gave the answer to yourself erlier, but you posted very good answer. Nicely done!